I'm trying to write a maven command but i get this error
I have been learning spring boot and in the course we use maven and the maven command was working at first but now it gives me this error.
./mvnw : The term './mvnw' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

+ ./mvnw clear
+ ~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./mvnw:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


I tried reinstaling maven and I tried to add the path to /bin file but still nothing.

...and I tried to add the path to /bin...   But you didn't do it right. New terminal always a good idea after changing environment variables

Is there a mvvw executable in your current directory?

Actually @FedericoklezCulloca that's a point - if you want t run 'proper' Maven then it should be mvn

@g00se You have mvnw if you have installed the Maven Wrapper

Thanks for that Mark. Had I known about that, I probably would never have written my alias that uses /tmp for the repo for experiments

Command you use ./mvnw is a command in Linux terminal. As I see in the error text it complains on cmdlet that is a command in PowerShell in Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview?view=powershell-7.4
You should add needed command to PowerShell or use Windows oriented command \.mvnw.bat if there is one. The last should work in ordinary command line.

Using ./mvnw instead of .\mvnw should work in PowerShell. The error means that there isn't a mvnw.bat in the current directory (you don't need to include the .bat when invoking it).

@MarkRotteveel is correct. More generally a lot of Windows tools nowadays support both \ and / for a directory separator. Powershell does for sure. And ./foo in PS is accepted as "run the executable foo in the current directory". It could be .bat or .ps1 or even an .exe.
